# Send Consecutive Posts

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, parallel.foreach, aggregateexception

I am wanting to sequentially send `POST()` data to a website.  I want post1 to finish, then begin post2, then begin post3 etc etc.  I have syntax that compiles, but I get an error of that I am unsure how to overcome.

> AggregateException was caught
>   One or more errors occured

Here is my syntax I use:

```
private multipost()
{
  string postsite = string.Format("http://requestb.in/1g5y7234");
  string postData = "";
  string responseMessage = "";

  DataTable grds = new DataTable();
  grds.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
  grds.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
  grds.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
  grds.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
  grds.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
  grds.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
  grds.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
  grds.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
  grds.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

  try
  {
    Parallel.ForEach(grds.Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), row =>
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            postData += "=" + item + "&";
            postData += "d2p=";
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest r = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(postsite);
            r.Method = "POST";
            r.Accept = "application/json";
            r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            r.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            r.KeepAlive = false;
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                try { sw.Write(postData); }
                catch (Exception ex) { responseMessage = ex.Message; }
            }
            var response = r.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(result);
            if (xml.Elements("success").FirstOrDefault().Value == "1") { responseMessage = "Success"; }
            else
            {
                var errors = xml.Elements("errors");
                foreach (var error in errors.Elements("error")) { responseMessage = error.Value; }
            }
        }
    });
  }
  catch (Exception mbop) { throw mbop; }      
}
```

Looks like I forgot to actually pose a question to the powerful minds.  What is causing this error, what do I do to overcome this error?

**EDIT**
I altered my `catch{}` block to

```
catch (Exception mbop) 
{
    while (mbop.InnerException != null)
        throw mbop;
}
```

And the `InnerException` it produced is

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Comment: Where does the exception happen? The aggregate exception does not tell much, just that there are a few of them

Comment: @AAlferez - it's a parallel.foreach so once that line is hit, it will wait maybe 15 seconds then go to the catch block.  F11 does not provide me with any further steps into the syntax.

Comment: Also, what you normally would do is have the try/catch outside saving the message, and in the inside try/catch you would do the throw

Comment: That postData does not seem well formed.

Comment: string loginjson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                userid = username.Text,
                password = pass.Text
            });

I would create whatever you send like this.
What is that ***JavaScriptSerializer json*** for?

Comment: @AAlferez JavaScriptSerializer can be removed, that was from a previous requirement.

Comment: @AAlferez - what does not look well formed to you in the string?

Comment: What is/look into `inner exception/s` (in Aggregate Exception). Hth..

Comment: what IS ACTUALLY the exception??

Comment: @Ahmedilyas -- see edit

Comment: Get rid of the `throw mbop;` line and replace it with `throw;` Get that exception, call `ToString()` on it, and append it to your question.

Comment: @Cameron - How would I call ToString() on the throw?  I edited my post to show how I generated the InnerException is that what you need to see to help troubleshoot?